# Should action class be linked to a single jsp or multiple jsp's could use same action class having multiple functions?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

This is the flow:

Initially JSP-1 is displayed having certain links, then after clicking on a link  `preprocess()` method of Action class is called which sets certain session variables.

Then JSP-2 is displayed which has a form to be filled.

So my question is:

Shall I use the same Action class having more <strike>functions</strike> methods or create a new Action class after form is submitted ??

Comment: Whatever suits your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

If the actions are independent of each other, meaning they accomplish completely different goals and share no duplicate code I would create an action class for each action.  If the actions perform similar operations and share several functions I would create multiple methods in the action class.

If they are very independent of each other but share similar code you may want to abstract out the codependent methods into their own class which is utilized by multiple action classes.  Its pretty much a judgement call and depends on the size of your application.

In frameworks such as Spring MVC "actions" are routed to different "controllers" by their URL.  Each controller contains a set of methods that loosely forms a cohesive unit, meaning their methods are related.